# Why is my workflow failing to send an email to a specific person?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow

My workflow looks for the name in a people picker field and then emails that person. It works for every name I put in the field except for 1 person (that I have seen so far). Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? This is the error I receive from the workflow.

> RequestorId: 06262505-fdc3-c27e-0000-000000000000. Details: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow
>   instance. Exception details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value
>   cannot be null. Parameter name: Input at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Comment: Have you checked that user's profile in UPSA? Is it same as any of the other users i.e. are all attributes present?

Comment: Does the user have an eMail adress in the userProfile?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2013 Workflow doesn't send email to an external user alike SharePoint 2010 Workflow.

The user to whom email is send via Workflow might not be synced in the User Profile, so perform a full User Profile Synchronization.

To perform full synchronization use [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee890104.aspx) link.

And if your user is already synced in the User Profile. Check its User Profile Properties whether they are mapped properly or not. And check that WorkEmail property is not blank.

If WorkEmail property is blank, perform manual user sync to AD:

```
$user = "domain/username"
$syncUser = Get-SPUser -Identity $user -web http://yoursite/
Set-SPUser -Identity $syncUser -SyncfromAD
```

Answer (score 0):

The reference that SharePoint has for the user may be out of sync with Active Directory.  You can run the PowerShell script below to update the user information from AD and then retry the workflow afterwards.

`Set-SPUser –Identity "<domain>\<username>" –SyncFromAD –Web http://<name of web app>`