# Exception details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I cannot identify which detail is being indicated as Null. Can someone help me?

The complete error message is:

> RequestorId: ac0d69b1-1903-ac70-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Input at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Comment: after what action you are getting this error.

Comment: Take a look at this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144330/why-is-my-workflow-failing-to-send-an-email-to-a-specific-person Are you also sending an email in workflow?

Answer (score 0):

i get this error after creating an item. The workflow will work fine upon creating item but when I check the workflow status, it doesnt get to completed. It results to suspended. So the moment I edit the item and save it, the workflow doesnt work anymore.

However, when I terminate the workflow and try to manually restart it, it works again.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this post and finds themselves with the following issue:

If you're using a workflow on a list that employs an InfoPath form, be sure to refresh fields on your form AFTER you've run the workflow once and BEFORE you republish your InfoPath form.

Otherwise, InfoPath will delete the workflow status field for your workflow and the workflow will fail with the above error.